# Expected number of steps to transform a permutation to the identity

Tags: probability

Start from an identity permutation P=[1,2,3,4,5], each step 
choose two random integers k and l in [1,5]. Then swap 
P[k] and P[l]. Stop the process until P again becomes 
identity. Observe that the expected number of steps 
is 120. I can not prove it theoretically. Please guide me.

Comment: "permutation identity" is a term of art which does *not* mean what you are using the term for; edited title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Choosing two values randomly and swapping them creates a doubly stochastic Markov chain on the space $\cal S$ of all permutations. The unique invariant probability distribution is uniform on this space, and (by Markov chain theory) the expected number of steps to return to the original position is the reciprocal of the mass at that state: i.e.,
$\mathbb{E}_e(T_e)=1/\pi(e)=|{\cal S}|=120$.

---

In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104299/dice-problem-throws-necessary-for-sum-multiple-of-n/104302#104302), I solve another problem with the same method and try to explain the result intuitively.

Comment: I've always wanted to learn more about Markov chains, but I have no idea where to start - what branch of mathematics is this considered *(that is, what should I be searching Amazon for :P)*?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Start with this free book! http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf

Comment: Also, see here: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read the book carefully.