# Conjugacy classes -- how to generate them for a list to be sorted?

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

In [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117150/using-markov-chains-to-analyze-a-ev-of-sorting-algorithm) I had brought up the notion of sorting a list of four randomly scrambled items.

It was mentioned that they can be broken down into 5 conjugacy classes:
(), (12), (123), (12)(34) and (1234)

Can anyone explain how these work or if there is a general way to list all possible conjugacies? For instance, what about a list of size 6?

Comment: In *what* other thread? It would be immensely better to actually link to it (or at least provide the link)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjugacy classes of the symmetric group $S_n$ correspond to the partitions of $n$. How to generate all partitions of $n$ is described e.g. in *The Art of Computer Programming* by Donald E. Knuth; see Algorithm P on p. 2 of [this online version](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/fasc3b.ps.gz).

Answer (score 1):

I write this answer only to make sure that OP realises the connection between the problem stated and the formulation. I think this however could be closed as exact duplicate.

---

The notion of sorting $n$ items  you're talking about is formally called the permutations of $n$ symbols. The notion of conjugacy discussed in the answer corresponds to the [action of group on itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) by [conjugation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class).

---

Well, you are asking for the number of conjugacy classes in a symmetric group of order $n$. Yes, there is a nice description.

I'll recall the main result while I'll let you go through the details in an exactly same answer $^\dagger$ I had written over here.

**Main result:**

The number of conjugacy classes in $S_n$ equals the number of partitions of $n$.

---

We'll give a way to list an exhaustive set or representatives for the conjugacy classes.

Write down all the additive partitions of $n$. To each partition, associate a representative as follows.

For each number appearing in the partition, attach with it a disjoint cycle of that length. The product of all such cycles represents a unique conjugacy class. It is best illustrated by an example for $4$:

$$\begin{align*}Id &\cong 1+1+1+1\\(1234)&\cong 4\\(12)(34) &\cong 2+2\\ (34) &\cong 1+1+2(\text{since (1) and (2) are omitted in this notation})\\(123)&\cong 3+1\end{align*}$$

---

$\dagger$ [This answer of mine deals with exactly this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/102198/21436)

Comment: Not sure I understand what your link is explaining.

If I partition a list of 6, I can have (12)(345)(6) for instance, but I could just as easily do (1)(234)(56) and yet both (12) and (56) would be considered part of the (12) conjugacy... unless I am totally misunderstanding what such classes represent here.

Comment: Neither do I understand what you mean. Do you understand what conjugacy means?

Comment: Perhaps not. I read the Wiki but I am not quite sure I get it in this case.

Comment: Well, then a more elementary question, do you understand what a group action on a set $X$ means?

Comment: Not in terms of jargon necessarily but likely the idea is simple

Comment: Yes, definitely, I am making no claim whatsoever about the complexity. But I was precise in my formulation of the question "do you _understand_ what group actions are?" You can understand them in your own way but do you first of all understand them was the tone of the question. =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2740/discussion-between-kannappan-sampath-and-john-smith)

Comment: I have moved the comment to a chat room [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2740/discussion-between-kannappan-sampath-and-john-smith) Please join me there for a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to add on to what Kanna wrote. In the answer he links he proves that permutations of the same [cycle type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) are all conjugate (and indeed that cycle type is necessarily invariant under conjugation, so that the conjugacy classes are *precisely* the cycle types). Ultimately this puts classes in bijection with [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). Explicitly, we may list representatives via

$$(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)\vdash n \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad (\underbrace{1\;2\;3\;\cdots}_{a_1})(\underbrace{\cdots\cdots}_{a_2})\cdots (\underbrace{\cdots n-1\; n}_{a_k})$$

For example, the integer partition $(3,2,2,1)\vdash8$ corresponds to the permutation $(123)(45)(67)(8)$.

Comment: @John: First, because the number 4 has exactly five integer partitions (1+1+1+1; 2+1+1; 2+2; 3+1; 4). Second, there is no canonical way to select a representative from each conjugacy class here afaik, so we could have just as easily picked (34) instead of (12) for the permutation corresponding to the partition (2,1,1). We picked arbitrarily.