# Expected value of number of draws

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, expectation

We have $5$ number in a bag: $(1,3,5,7,9)$. We draw one from the bag and then put it back. We do this until the sum of the numbers can be divided by $3$. Whats the expected value of the number of draws?

My idea was to solve it with Markov-chains:
States: $0,1,2$. So numbers$\mod 3$.

The matrix will be:
$\begin{pmatrix}
2/5 & 2/5 & 1/5 \\
1/5 & 2/5 & 2/5 \\
2/5 & 1/5 & 2/5
\end{pmatrix}$

Then we have an equation system: 
$k_1=1+2/5k_1+2/5k_2$, $\ k_2=1+1/5k_1+2/5k_2$ and $k_3=0$.

Even if I solve this, I'm not sure how to continue. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use your idea, but partly for ease of typing we use different notation. Say that we are in State $1$ if the sum so far is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$, and that we are in State $2$ if the sum is congruent to $2$. Let $m$ be the mean waiting time.  Let $a_1$ be the *additional* mean waiting time, given we are in State $1$, and $a_2$ the additional mean waiting time given that we are in State $2$.

On the first pick, we either get something divisible by $3$, in which case we have spent $1$ pick, and our additional waiting time is $0$. Or else we get a $1$ or a $7$, and our mean additional waiting time is $a_1$. Or else we get a $5$, and our mean additional waiting time is $a_2$. Thus
$$m=1+\frac{2}{5}a_1+\frac{1}{5}a_2.\tag{1}$$
Suppose we are in State $1$, and do another trial.  If we get a $3$ or a $9$, we stay in State $1$, and our additional expected time remains at $a_1$. If we get a $1$ or a $7$, our additional expected waiting time becomes $a_2$. And if we get $5$, we are finished. Thus
$$a_1=1+\frac{2}{5}a_1+\frac{2}{5}a_2.\tag{2}$$
Similarly, 
$$a_2=1+\frac{1}{5}a_1+\frac{2}{5}a_2.\tag{3}$$
Solve the last two equations for $a_1$ and $a_2$, and substitute in Equation (1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I asked a bit above, is there a more simple way to calculate the expected number of draws? If we cant use discrete stochastic processes.

Comment: The answer by Byron Schmuland is far more efficient. But I cannot think of a way fundamentally different from the one above in general. For a larger number of states, one would want to express things in matrix terms, and use linear algebra machinery.

Comment: In your first equation, should it be m = 1 + 2/5*a_1 + 1/5*a_2 + 2/5? As you have 2/5 chance to get a number which is divisible by 3 at first draw.

Answer (score 4):

Since $P$ is a doubly stochastic matrix, the invariant measure is uniform,
i.e., $\pi=(1/3,1/3,1/3)$. Therefore the expected number of steps to return to  state $0$ is $\mathbb{E}_0(T_0)=1/\pi_0=3$.

This is a method well worth knowing, and I've used it before on 
this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104299/dice-problem-throws-necessary-for-sum-multiple-of-n/104302#104302), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114088/expected-number-of-steps-to-transform-a-permutation-to-the-identity/114096#114096), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191518/random-walking-and-the-expected-value/191533#191533), for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way to solve this problem? Without using the Markov-theory. I was thinking about fit a binomial distibution or just calculate the distribution and then the expected value by definiton but It seemed to be way harder.

Answer (score 3):

We may also consider an absorbing markov chain:

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\
0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\
0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

Expected time to absorbing state is then given by

$$(I-Q)^{-1}\cdot c$$
where
$$
I=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),
Q=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\
0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{2}{5}
\end{array}\right), c= \left(\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{array}\right)$$

which is 3.