# Mean number of tosses of a fair dice to get a sum of outcomes being a multiple of $5$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> Let $S_n$ denote the sum of the outcomes of the $n$ tosses of a fair dice. Let $T=\inf\{n>0: S_n$ is a multiple of $5\}$. Compute $E(T)$
>   (by means of markov chains).

**Attempt.**  Instead of working with $S_n$,we shal work with $S_n$ mod $5$. So $T$ becomes $T=\inf\{n\geq 1: S_n =0\}$. The chain $\{S_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is markov, with state space $\mathbb{X}=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and 
transition probabilities $p(k,m)=1/6$ for 
$m \in \mathbb{X}\setminus \{k+1\}$ and $p(k,k+1)=2/6$. 
I wonder which of the following is the right path to the solution.

**Option one.** According to one step analysis, the function $g(x)=E(T~|~S_1=x),~x\in \mathbb{X}$ satisfies:
$$g(x)=\sum_{y\in \mathbb{X}}p(x,y)g(y)$$
and we solve somehow for $g(0),\ldots,g(4).$  So $$E(T)=E(E(T|S_1))=\sum_{x\in \mathbb{X}}P(S_1=x)E(T|S_1=x)=\frac{1}{6}g(0)+\frac{2}{6}g(1)+\ldots+\frac{1}{6}g(4).$$

**Option two.** $T$ is indeed a time of   first return to a state $x_0\in \mathbb{X}$ (that I don't know..). In that case we work with limit distributions 
$\pi=\pi P$ (it exists since the chain is aperiodic, irreducible and has finite state space), so $E(T)=1/\pi(x_0).$

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104299/dice-problem-throws-necessary-for-sum-multiple-of-n/104302#104302

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very useful! Let me just point out this remark: in terms of the symbols used above, you consider the chain to start from zero, that is $S_0=0$ (making $T$ in that case the time of first return to state zero)?

Comment: Yes, we define $S_0=0$.

Comment: I thought of that myself for a moment, but I was kind of skeptic about how "natural" is to define $S_0$. Also, do we do consider this "natural" condition, for technical reasons? That is, in order for $T$ to be a time of return (and work it through invariant distributions)?

Answer (score 1):

(*Update:* Your Option One is the way to go; but you forgot to add $1$ for each step. Apart from this my $e_k$ are essentially your $E(T|S_1=k)$, as well as the $\tau_k$ of Nikolaos Skout's answer; but my handling of $e_0$ gives the correct value $5$.)

Denote by $e_k$ $(0\leq k\leq4)$ the expected number of additional throws if your current remainder is $k$, but the game is not yet over. Then you obtain five equations, a sample being
$$e_3=1+{1\over6}(e_1+e_2+e_3+2e_4)\ .$$
Solving this system I obtained $e_0=5$ (which is the answer to your problem), $e_1={1554\over311}$, and so on.

Comment: @Cristian Blatter thank very much for your answer. To connect it somehow also with the statement at the beggining, is it true that $E(T|S_1=k)=e_k$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$ ($T$ as stated above)?

Answer (score 0):

Working in $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$ is a good start. The transition probabilities are then
$$
P(i,j) = \begin{cases}
\frac13,& j\equiv i+1\pmod 5\\
\frac16,& j\not\equiv i+1\pmod 5.
\end{cases}
$$
Let $\tau_i=\mathbb E[T\mid S_1=i]$ for $i\in \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$. Conditioning on $S_1$ yields the system of equations
\begin{align}
\tau_0 &= 1\\
\tau_1 &= 1 + \frac13\tau_2 + \frac16(\tau_1+\tau_3+\tau_4)\\
\tau_2 &= 1+ \frac13\tau_3 + \frac16(\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_4)\\
\tau_3 &= 1+ \frac13\tau_4 + \frac16(\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3)\\
\tau_4 &= 1 + \frac16(\tau_1+\tau_2+\tau_3+\tau_4).
\end{align}
We may rewrite these in matrix form $A\vec \tau=\vec b$ where $$A= \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{5}{6} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{6} \\
 -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{6} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{6} \\
 -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{6} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
 -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{6} \\
\end{array}
\right],\quad \vec\tau= \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \tau _1 \\
 \tau _2 \\
 \tau _3 \\
 \tau _4 \\
\end{array}
\right],\quad \vec b=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right].$$
Solving $A\vec\tau=\vec b$ yields
$$\vec\tau = \frac1{311}\begin{bmatrix}1554\\1548\\1512\\1296\end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one question: which of all $\tau_i$'s is the desired mean we are looking for?

Comment: Whichever state the Markov chain starts in (you didn't specify the distribution of $S_0$).

Comment: An idea is to consider $S_0=0$, since we start we zero sum! But this would mean that the desired number is $\tau_0=1$? (which is not true I guess)

Comment: $T$ was defined so that $\mathbb P(T>0)=1$, so that isn't a problem.

Comment: Yes, but the final solution should be 5 i guess.