# The expected number of throws of $n$-faced dice till the sum of number is a multiple of $m$

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, puzzle, dice

Consider a fair dice with **$n$ sides**, numbered from $1$ to $n$. Imagine this dice is rolled over and over until the cumulative sum of the rolls is divisible by $m$. The question we seek to answer is: **What is the average number of rolls required to reach this condition?**

[There is a theorem: For $6$-faced dice, the expected number of throws till the sum of the number is a multiple of $m$ is $m$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104299/dice-problem-throws-necessary-for-sum-multiple-of-n?rq=1)

What's the result for $n$-faced dice?

Comment: Perhaps this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104299/dice-problem-throws-necessary-for-sum-multiple-of-n?rq=1 could help?

Comment: @Studentmath What's the result of $n$-faced dice?

Comment: In the answer to the linked question, it states it does not matter how many sides the dice has - the argument still holds.